# Downloading all of the files in a specific folder with PyDrive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-workspace, pydrive

My Google Drive looks something like this:

> picture1.jpg
>
> song1.mp3
>
> a/b/file1.txt
>
> a/b/file2.txt
>
> a/b/file3.jpg
>
> a/b/file4.m4a
>
> a/b/...

I want to use PyDrive to download every file in folder "b". After looking at the documentation and checking StackOverflow, I still cannot figure out how to do this. How would I download all of the files in folder "b" (which is contained in folder "a") using PyDrive. Also, in case it's relevant please note that folder "b" contains thousands of files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically you need to use the file id to list or download a folder's contents.

Assuming that file_list is the root directory:

```
for file1 in file_list:
    if file1['title'] == '[name_of_target_folder]':
        folder_id = file1['id']
```

Then

```
> folder_id 
> 'WIU1xyz19g83abcdefg'
```

(for example)

get every file in 'folder':

```
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'{}' in parents and trashed=false".format(folder_id)}).GetList()
```

download every file in 'folder':

```
for i, file1 in enumerate(sorted(file_list, key = lambda x: x['title']), start=1):
    print('Downloading {} from GDrive ({}/{})'.format(file1['title'], i, len(file_list)))
    file1.GetContentFile(file1['title'])
```

Comment: Downloading each file individually seems incredibly slow when I run it.  Is there no way to just grab an entire directory at once?

Comment: @james - I have around 30K files and the ListFile command takes ages - is there any recommendation ?!

Comment: @user702846 I think this is probably what you're looking for: https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filelist.html#paginate-and-iterate-through-files (see the second section on pagination/iteration).